# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I have a lot of exciting things happening in my life right now (building a new house!) and have found that I am spending less time on the computer. I've decided to step away as moderator of Pets.SE to make room for someone who can be more responsive and present on the site. I will still be around, just less so.

Thank you James Jenkins and John Cavan for being such wonderful folks to co-moderate with. Thank you to everyone on this site for being such a wonderful community! I have really enjoyed my time helping this site grow into such a great resource.

Comment: We're gonna miss ya on the team! :(

Comment: I don't know whether to downvote out of sadness, or to upvote as a thank you for doing an awesome job.

Comment: I am up voting as a thank you, @AshleyNunn can down vote for sadness.  Hopefully we will still be seeing you around.  You have enough rep that you probably still have access to most or all of the tools, so don't be a stranger.

Comment: Thank you for all you've done for this site, and good luck with the upcoming excitement!  See you around, I trust.

Comment: Good luck, Z., and thanks!